# Getting Resources$NotFoundException on espresso when trying to access test resources

Tags: android, android-espresso

I'm getting `android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID` when trying to access resources defined in the `androidTest/res` during runtime on my tests. I've tried a couple of things and no luck. Isn't this supposed to work? My code sample:

**ExampleInstrumentedTest.kt**

```kotlin
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class ExampleInstrumentedTest {
    @Test
    fun test() {
        val result = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().targetContext.getString(
            com.myproject.test.R.string.my_test
        )
        assertEquals("my test", result)
    }
}
```

**strings.xml**

```xml
<resources>
    <string name="my_test">my test</string>
</resources>
```

Has anyone faced this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution for this. The issue at hand is that `InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().targetContext` will only be able to access what's included in the application being tested, so in this case I should use `InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().context`, which will be able to access test resources. For reference:

**getTargetContext**
Return a Context for the target application being instrumented. Note that this is often different than the Context of the instrumentation code, since the instrumentation code often lives is a different package than that of the application it is running against. See getContext() to retrieve a Context for the instrumentation code.

**getContext**
Return the Context of this instrumentation's package. Note that this is often different than the Context of the application being instrumentated, since the instrumentation code often lives is a different package than that of the application it is running against. See getTargetContext() to retrieve a Context for the target application.

from doc: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Instrumentation